# keyword can't be an expression error while using filter

Tags: python, filter

I used below statements in Python but it is throwing an error

```
tbl_ProvJenny_AppGoalSetting = Table('tbl_ProvJenny_AppGoalSetting', metadata, autoload=True,autoload_with=engine,schema='dbo')
row= session.query(func.max(tbl_ProvJenny_AppGoalSetting.c.EffectiveDate)).filter(tbl_ProvJenny_AppGoalSetting.c.MerticTypeLkup=1002)
```

```
Error
    row= session.query(func.max(tbl_ProvJenny_AppGoalSetting.c.EffectiveDate)).filter([tbl_ProvJenny_AppGoalSetting].MerticTypeLkup=1002)
                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
filter([tbl_ProvJenny_AppGoalSetting].MerticTypeLkup=1002)
```

Is invalid syntax because a *keyword argument* can't look like `[tbl_ProvJenny_AppGoalSetting].MerticTypeLkup` - only names are allowed, like:

```
filter(some_name=6)
```

Did you mean to use a comma instead of the dot?

```
filter([tbl_ProvJenny_AppGoalSetting], MerticTypeLkup=1002)
   now you're passing two arguments  ^^^^
```

If you intended to set `[tbl_ProvJenny_AppGoalSetting].MerticTypeLkup` to 1002 and pass that to the function, do that:

```
[tbl_ProvJenny_AppGoalSetting].MerticTypeLkup = 1002
filter([tbl_ProvJenny_AppGoalSetting].MerticTypeLkup)
```

---

Actually, I think this error message is very misleading because "keyword" usually means "keyword of the language", like `def`, `return` and `if`, *not* "keyword *argument*", as in this case.